# Access PostgreSQL SELECT list in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, where-clause

Does PostgreSQL support access the `SELECT` list in the `WHERE` clause somehow? Was not able to find any documentation about it.

Example 1:

```
SELECT my_column as xpto FROM my_table WHERE other_column = xpto
```

*I'm using the example above as a usage only, I know it does not make sense.*

Example 2:

Considering `my_column` as a `Datetime` column.

```
SELECT my_column + interval '1 year' as xpto FROM my_table WHERE other_column >= xpto
```

*The example above may lead to a better usage example of it.*

Comment: See accepted answer here [WHERE column alias doesn't work](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/225874/using-column-alias-in-a-where-clause-doesnt-work).

Comment: thanks @AdrianKlaver very clarifying